# how to use "robotlocomotion drake" codes in my project, for example "qp_inverse_dynamics"

Tags: installation, open-source, robotics, drake

i want to implement drake in my project, but i found it almost impossible. 
Although there are notebooks and course explain robotics theory and how drake works, 
http://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/underactuated.html?chapter=drake
https://www.edx.org/course/underactuated-robotics-mitx-6-832x-0

But how could i use the codes in drake in my project. For example, i want to simulate a 6-Dof arm using V-rep and ROS, and i want to inplement force control to the arm using "qp_inverse_dynamics" in drake, do i need to include all files that "qp_inverse_dynamics" used, and construct the build system? There are tons of files.

I have made a quadruped robot using position control and PID controller, and have a little bit experience of using open source convex quadratic programs solver(osqp)。
And now, after build and tested drake using bazel, what coule I do to use codes in drake in my project? Or should I just write my own codes using the method in Underactuated Robotics notebook?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This repository is our working example of how to use drake in your own project:
https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-shambhala

We do support OSQP as one of many solver backends.  There is a chance that you will find that you want some feature in drake that is not yet exposed in the binary installation, in which case please make a request on github.  But I suspect it should work well for you.

N.B.  The lectures you've pointed to on edX are a few years old now.  The current version of the course is running right now, with streamed/recorded lectures available at http://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/Spring2018/index.html#textbook/assignments/videos

Comment: Oh，i will try to use drake-shambhala version，thanks very much ，Gesar～